# $\tau$ pair production question

Tags: homework-and-exercises, special-relativity, particle-physics, pair-production

There's a question on my homework about the process $e^{-} e^{+} \rightarrow \tau^{+} \tau^{-}$. Specifically, it is claimed that the minimum energy required of the colliding positron and electron beams is slightly less than twice the $\tau$ mass, and I am asked to explain this deviation and compute it. In the context of this course, we have only discussed the relativistic kinematics of such processes (which would predict a minimum energy of twice the $\tau$ mass), so I am not sure what might be responsible. I'm grasping at straws here, but might it have something to do with the Coulomb interaction between the opposite charges? Thanks in advance.

Comment: It may (or may not) be significant that particle physicists often use "energy" in this kind of context to mean the *kinetic energy* of the beam. Of course in the reaction in question the electrons will be in the ultra-relativistic regime so the difference is trivial, so that may not be what is intended.

Comment: Maybe the homework intends you not to count electron rest masses as required "energy" required.   Perhaps, the idea here is that they're going for energy that an experimentalist would put into the two electrons to get the reaction to go, and that the energy from the electron's rest mass comes for free.

Comment: Another possibility. If the Tau-pair is produced almost at rest they could (in principle, I don't know if it is possible in practice) form a short-lived bound state at total energy just slightly less that $2m_\tau$.

Comment: I assumed it was something less trivial than the electron/positron rest energies, but maybe not. I was thinking it would be something more along the lines of dmckee's second idea

Comment: I'm not sure, but I think maybe @mikefallopian may be on the right track with the Coloumb interaction. The Coloumb interaction between two electrons at the collision point is $\sim 2 \alpha m \sim 10keV$, not negligible. 

In the extreme case, if you for example released an electron positron from rest a short distance away from each other, I presume they could collide and produce new particles.

Comment: @JeffDror, how did you decide on the value $2 \alpha m$? That would seem to imply that the electrons annihilate at a mean separation of $1/(2m)$, and I don't know where that comes from

Comment: @mikefallopian Sorry, I wasn't clear. I was taking the Compton wavelength to be roughly the collision distance.

Comment: @mikefallopian I think what I said was wrong. In order for a electron-positron to annihilate, I believe they first need to overcome this potential barrier. So the net result is that they would gain kinetic energy as they get closer and closer, but then "give it back" to annihilate. Otherwise energy would not be conserved. So it won't  result in needing less initial energy.

Comment: *" I believe they first need to overcome this potential barrier."* @JeffDror The potential is negative (unlike charges attract, after all). But you only get energy back from that if the taus end bound.

Comment: @dmckee, right before the charges annihilate they each have negative potential energy. They have to gain that energy back to annihilate. For example, suppose you have an electron-positron pair that start out far away from each other. Their initial kinetic and potential energy are both zero. As they begin to move toward each other they gain a large kinetic energy and lose potential energy. If they then annihilate and produce for simplicity, two photons, the photons would have very low energies (each with $E=m_e$). The $e^-,e^+$ "used up" their kinetic energy to overcome the potential barrier.

Comment: @Jeff The virtual photon is off-shell. It does not have to obey energy conservation the pair of tau-leptons is on-shell. It does have to obey energy conservation, but they are in the same potential well that the electrons were in (they have charges $\pm e$, too). If they were to move to separate to a great distance they have to give that energy up again, but if they bind they get to keep a some of it, an because the taus are much heavier than electrons ending bound is a possibility. Nor does the initial annihilation have to take place at rest; both SLAC and LEP did it at quite high energies.

Comment: I talked to my professor and what he is looking for is, in fact, the tau-antitau bound state having mass slightly less than $2m_\tau$

Comment: @dmckee, I think this is getting off topic. I agree with what you saying. I was just pointing out (in response to my own original comment) that an electron-positron pair needs to "give back" some kinetic energy at the point of annihilation so the Coulomb attraction between the electron-positron prior to annihilation is irrelevant. The $\tau,\tau^+$ bound state will certainly have a lower energy and can be produced at lower electron-positron energies as you initially stated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that $\tau^-\tau^+$ can form a bound state similarly to positronium($e^-e^+$), all we need is the form of the ground state of positronium, specifically that it is proportional to the reduced mass of the pair: $\mu = \frac{m_1m_2}{m_1+m_2}$.

Knowing that positronium's ground state is $(-13.6/2)= -6.8$ eV and that the new reduced mass for the Tau particle bound state is simply $\frac{m_{Tau}}{2} = \frac{m_{Tau}}{m_e}\mu_{e^-e^+}$

It follows that the energy of the Tau particle bound state is this factor, $\frac{m_{Tau}}{m_e}$ multiplied by $-6.8$ eV.
$(-6.8)(3477) = -2.36\times10^4$ eV